# Is there a way to complete maps?

Tags: trimps

I've been through my first map a few times now, and I picked up upgrades to my gear the first 3 times through. Now I'm getting nothing but food and gems. The map seems to continually reset, so I decided to see what other maps there were.

After collecting some map fragments and creating a map, I'm told:

> You must finish or recycle your current map before moving on.

How do I "finish" the current map? Is there a point where it stops repeating?

Comment: Have you tried turning "Repeat Off" and letting the map finish?

Comment: @Chippies Wow. No I did not. It doesn't make it clear that I need to finish the current run. Post that as the answer, please!

Comment: Did that actually work? I was just guessing, as I haven't got that far myself :P

Comment: @Chippies It did. The message went away and I'm on the next map.

Comment: Posted an answer, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning the "Repeat Off" and allowing the run to finish should make the message go away.